# Is there any way to scrape YouTube comments by specific keywords?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping

I want to scrape YouTube comments but only those which have a particular keyword in them. And that keyword will be set by me. For example, if I only want comments with the word "password" in them. So, can I do something like that?

I am scraping using Google Spreadsheets Apps Script. I have managed to scrape all comments, with and without replies.

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue and what you have tried so far. Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
let wantedComments = [];
let keyword = "keyword"
let re = new RegExp(`${keyword}`,'g');
commentslist.forEach(c => {
  if(c.match(r)) {
    wantedComments.push(c)
  }
});
```

Presumably you will be getting a list from the youtube api in the form of an array.  So loop through it a run it through the loop to only capture the ones with you keyword.

Comment: No, actually I am using Google sheets for the web scraping. So, I get the output listed in the Google sheets.

Comment: I prefer using chrome snippets to collect data from from youtube.  I find it much easier since the dom is live